# I am unable to get my login page to disappear after I hit "Sign In"

Tags: reactjs, react-router, navbar

I have created file(s) named "LoginForm", "Navbar", "Home", "About", and "Contact" that all have their respective basic components.

When I try to render them all into my app, I want the login screen to appear first. I then have it set up to where I click "Sign in" and it is supposed to link to my home page, where the navbar then can be accessed and toggled.

I am for some reason able to reach the home page when clicking "Sign in", but the login screen does not go away.

My code is below, with the routes to each page and the switch to specify exact path.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';
import Contact from './components/Contact';

class App extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
        <Router>
            <Route path="/" component={LoginForm} />
                <Navbar />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                        <Route path="/Home" exact component={Home} />
                        <Route path="/About" exact component={About} />
                        <Route path="/Contact" exact component={Contact} />
                    </Switch>
        </Router>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two routes with same path, this will always render when the path is "/":

```
<Route path="/" component={LoginForm} />
```

The switch will render the first child route that matches the path, so this will also render:

```
<Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change route outside switch component.

Try this code :

```
<Router>
                <Navbar />
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={LoginForm} />
                        <Route path="/Home" component={Home} />
                        <Route path="/About" component={About} />
                        <Route path="/Contact"component={Contact} />
                    </Switch>
        </Router>
```

You need to put your Route inside Switch if you need to use Link.
You had two route rendering Home
Use one exact path

Comment: I had actually stumbled upon this solution as I persisted trial and error, However. The problem now remains that everything works as intended, except when the "login" page first appears, I can't get rid of the Navigation bar. Only until after I click sign in, or change the URL, does the login screen disappear.

Comment: You want to display navbar after logged in ?

Comment: I want only the login screen to display when you navigate to the page, and after clicking "sign in", I want the login screen to disappear, only leaving the navigation bar and website to display. As of now, the navigation bar displays on the login screen.

Comment: For this case you need to put NavBar component inside other component, It's only solution I think

Comment: In what way would I go about that?

Comment: just nest your navbar component into other component